EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found, but most answers on stackoverflow don't solve the issue
I have a problem, and I have seen several questions similar to mine, but none of the answers have helped me. Basically, I am creating an Express Rest API with Typeform, and I want to add a small seeder (Note: I tried Faker, and I couldn't make it work, but because I do not need anything fancy, I opted to do it by hand).
I created a script that I run on package.json this way
"scripts": {
    "db:seed:dev": "docker compose run backend pnpm ts-node scripts/seed/dev.ts",
}

But when I run the scripts, I receive this error message:
if (!metadata) throw new EntityMetadataNotFoundError(target)
                             ^
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found.

Most answers point to adding the entities on the entities field, but as you can see, I did it. I also tried other ways, like adding
entities: ['../entities/**/*.ts'], // it is a typescript system

or
entities: ['../entities/**/*.js'],

Recently, I've been importing Users and adding the class directly to entities, but the result is the same. Next is the entire seed script.
Note: I added to the seed script an independent configuration instead of reusing the one I use on the application in case that was conflicting
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from '../../src/entities/user';
import { genPassword } from '../../src/lib/passwordUtils';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

(async () => {
  dotenv.config();

  const {
    POSTGRES_HOSTNAME,
    POSTGRES_PORT,
    POSTGRES_USER,
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    POSTGRES_DB,
    NODE_ENV,
  } = process.env;
  console.log(POSTGRES_HOSTNAME);
  console.log(POSTGRES_PORT);
  console.log(POSTGRES_USER);
  console.log(POSTGRES_PASSWORD);
  console.log(POSTGRES_DB);

  const appDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: POSTGRES_HOSTNAME,
    port: parseInt(POSTGRES_PORT || '5432'),
    username: POSTGRES_USER,
    password: POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
    database: POSTGRES_DB,
    logging: true,
    synchronize: true,
    entities: [User],
  });

  appDataSource
    .initialize()
    .then((dataSource) => {
      console.log('Data Source has been initialized inside script!');
      return dataSource;
    })
    .catch((err: Error) => {
      console.error(
        'Error during Data Source initialization inside script',
        err
      );
      return err;
    });

  const userRepository = appDataSource.getRepository(User);
  const users = [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      email: 'example1@example.com',
      name: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      hash: genPassword('12345').hash,
      salt: genPassword('12345').salt,
      createdAt: Date(),
      updatedAt: Date(),
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      email: 'example2@example.com',
      name: 'Jack',
      lastName: 'Smith',
      hash: genPassword('45323').hash,
      salt: genPassword('45323').salt,
      createdAt: Date(),
      updatedAt: Date(),
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      email: 'example3@example.com',
      name: 'Jane',
      lastName: 'Doe',
      hash: genPassword('43210').hash,
      salt: genPassword('43210').salt,
      createdAt: Date(),
      updatedAt: Date(),
    },
  ];
  console.log(users);
  await userRepository.insert(users);
})();

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
